# Converting an array to a nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**What I'm trying to do:**
I am trying to dynamically update a scope with AngularJS in a directive, based on the ngModel.

**A little back story:**
I noticed Angular is treating my ngModel strings as a string instead of an object.  So if I have this:

```
ng-model="formdata.reports.first_name"
```

If I try to pull the ngModel in a directive, and assign something to it, I end up with $scope["formdata.reports.first_name"].  It treats it as a string instead of a nested object.

**What I am doing now:**
I figured the only way to get this to work would be to split the ngModel string into an array, so I am now working with:

```
models = ["formdata", "reports", "first_name"];
```

This works pretty good, and I am able to use dynamic values on a static length now, like this:

```
$scope[models[0]][models[1]][models[2]] = "Bob";
```

**The question:**
How do I make the length of the dynamic scope dynamic? I want this to be scalable for 100 nested objects if needed, or even just 1.

UPDATE:
I was able to make this semi-dynamic using if statements, but how would I use a for loop so I didn't have a "max"?

```
if (models[0]) {
    if (models[1]) {
        if (models[2]) {
            if (models[3]) {
                $scope[models[0]][models[1]][models[2]][models[3]] = "Bob";
            } else {
                $scope[models[0]][models[1]][models[2]] = "Bob";
            }
        } else {
            $scope[models[0]][models[1]] = "Bob";
        }
    } else {
        $scope[models[0]] = "Bob";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does $scope.formdata.reports.first_name work in your directive?

Comment: Yes, and the databinding works also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to

> I noticed Angular is treating my ngModel strings as a string instead of an object

Add the `require` property to your directive then add a fourth `ctrl` argument to your `link` function

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
      // Now you have access to ngModelController for whatever you passed in with the ng-model="" attribute
      ctrl.$setViewValue('x');
    }
  };
});
```

Demonstration: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fcl4cUXpdE5w6fHMGUgC

Comment: Wow that helps so much.  I knew I was overthinking this!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic pathing:

```
var obj = $scope;

for (var i = 0; i<models.length-1; i++) {
  obj = obj[models[i]];
}
obj[models[models.length-1]] = 'Bob';
```

Obviously no checks are made, so if the path is wrong it will fail with an error. I find your original problem with angular suspicious, perhaps you could explore a bit in that direction before you resort to this workaround.

Comment: I'm doing this so ng-model="formdata.reports.first_name" can be changed to either "first_name" or "formdata.reports.fe.fi.fo.fum.first_name" without breaking my directive.  I don't know, maybe I'm overthinking things?